# Why game-developers have to optimize apps for different number cores?

Tags: multithreading, game-engine

I often hear that if some game is optimized for 4-cores CPU, it will not work better on 8-cores CPU for example.
Does this statement have sense?
As a web-developer I can't understand it, because I used to write apps, which distribute resource-demanding tasks by all available threads, depending on number of available cores, without any rebuilds. The more cores, the better performance.
Could you explain me on some example, why some games cannot be adjusted for greater number of cores automatically?

Comment: where have you read it? it doesn't seem reasonable. most game engines I know simply use a threadpool which scales according to the number of cores

Comment: @DavidHaim in PlayerUnknownsBattlegrounds for example you will have to add a custom start parameter to tell the game to use all cores. What are possible reasons for this? Back in the days i thought the OS would handle which process is allowed to use which cores.